# How to have the prepropressor cpp to expand macro in fortran function name

Tags: fortran, preprocessor

I have got a very simple problem using the cpp preprocessor on a Fortran file: why is `MACRO` in the following code not expanded in the subroutine name `fooMACRO` (but it is elsewhere)?

```
#define MACRO 'bye'
#define MSG 'hello world'

      subroutine fooMACRO()

      print*, MACRO

      end subrountine

      program hello

      print*, MSG 
      call fooMACRO()

      end program
```

It gives

```
$ gfortran-E helloworld.F                                                                               
# 1 "helloworld.F"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "helloworld.F"



      subroutine fooMACRO()

      print*, 'bye'

      end subrountine

      program hello

      print*, 'hello world' 
      call fooMACRO()

      end program
```

Comment: The C preprocessor tokenizes its input.  'fooMACRO' is a token that does not match 'MACRO', so it does not get expanded.

Comment: Is there any way to force the expension in this case?

Comment: You can use ## for string concatenation, but not in gfortran.

Comment: @VladimirF is there any way to get gfortran to concatenate a macro argument with text?

Comment: you can use cpp separately.